# Open an inbuilt android activity using intent. Nothing happens when i press the button or Textview(i made it as a button) for that matter.PleaseHelp

Tags: android, android-intent

This is the scr java file TestingbankaiActivity.java

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class TestingbankaiActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
Button b;
TextView tv;

// Class c,c1;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.testingactivity);
    initialize();

}

private void initialize() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b1);
    tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvb1);
}

public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch (v.getId()) {

    case R.id.b1:

        Intent i = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_DIAL,
                Uri.parse("tel:9642777959"));
        startActivity(i);
        break;

    case R.id.tvb1:

        Intent i1 = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_DIAL,
                Uri.parse("tel:9642777959"));
        startActivity(i1);
        break;

    }

}
}

this is the xml file .

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/b1"
    android:layout_width="70dip"
    android:layout_height="70dip"
    android:text="hhhh" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvb1"
    android:layout_width="50dip"
    android:layout_height="50dip"
    android:text="hha" />

</LinearLayout>



This is the manifest file

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.testing.bankai"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <activity
        android:name=".TestingbankaiActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

In the end i am getting the screen with a text view and a button. What i want is if the user presses the textview or the button it should that to the action dial intent.

Answer (score 1):

You need to link the "click the button/textview" event to your code. All you have done is created the buttons, but you've not set up the `OnClickListener`. There are 2 ways to do this:

1) Add the following to the layout.xml for your Button and TextView:

```
android:onClick="onClick"
```

2) Add the following code to your `initialize()` method:

```
b.setOnClickListener(this);
tv.setOnClickListener(this);
```

Comment: oh my god.i feel so stupid.Thank you a lot!!